# No table created in db.sqlite3 after migrate and makemigrates in Django

Tags: django

I did this command and after that, only the DB file was created without any tables.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

also I use the app name in this commands but nothing changed.

After that, I saw this DB file:

[image]

Comment: Did you add those app name in settings.py in the section "INSTALLED_APPS" ?

Comment: Yes I did. I added it in setting.py  
Also I use this commands:

python manage.py makemigrations Appname
python manage.py migrate Appname

Comment: and what message came when you run python manage.py migrate ?

Comment: every thing is OK after that.

Comment: I found the problem. The DB browser in my Pycharm was my issue. I update my Sqlite(Xerial) and after that, solved. I browsed it and can saw the table in it.